# Qt - How to add edge nodes onto a QWidget which enable users to drag to resize QWidget

Tags: qt

I'm doing a screenshot feature. And once the select area (QWidget) is decided, user can drag one of the edge nodes of the select area so that it can be expanded to capture more contents of the screen.

The picture below shows what I expect to do:

[image]

But I have no idea how to create these nodes on the edges of a QWidget - the **Select Area**. Or maybe there is something subclassed from QWidget class which can help?

Comment: Can't you make use of something like [`QRubberBand`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrubberband.html)?

Comment: If you implement the nodes manually, seems they are going to be 8 more small widgets, I'd say